# Were there any other Immortals aside from Connor and Duncan MacLeod who were relatives?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise

Connor and Duncan MacLeod seem to be somewhat related (they are of the same Highlander clan).

Were there any other Immortals in the *Highlander* franchise who were related to at least the same degree, or were the MacLeods an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They were not related, but they were raised in the same clan.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duncan_MacLeod):

> In the eleventh episode, "Family Tree", Duncan's father and Chieftain of Clan MacLeod, Ian MacLeod, states that the newborn Duncan was a foundling given to his wife Mary to replace the stillborn son she had delivered, and raised to be his successor.

Essentially, he was adopted.

I don't recall of anything else similar from the films or TV show, however.

Comment: I believe most immortals whose pasts were investigated ended up being foundlings. Richie Ryan, while searching for his father, Jack Ryan, discovers that the woman he believed to be his mother, Emily Ryan, was in fact a foster carer. This does raise the question of where these little immortal babies came from that I don't think was ever answered.

Comment: True.  Did they ever mention anything about Methos' parents or lack thereof?